# Java sockets help client-server

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, java-threads

I need help to do a java practice with threads.
I wanted this program to give me back the information that the clients are writing with their name and the message time. This is the code I have for the moment.
In the same way I have messages that I can not get the program to print
thank you very much, any help is appreciated.

**SERVER**

```
public class Servidor {

public static void main(String[] args) {

ServerSocket servidor;
Socket conexion;
DataOutputStream salida;
DataInputStream entrada;
 int num = 0;

 try{

     //Vamos a crear un serverSocket en el puerto seleccionado
     servidor = new ServerSocket();
     System.out.println("Servidor arrancado correctamente");

     while(true){

         //Se espera a la conexion de alguno de los clientes
         conexion = servidor.accept();
         num++;
         System.out.println("Conexión numero"+num+" desde: " + conexion.getInetAddress().getHostName());

         //Abrimos ahora los canales de entrada y salida
         entrada = new DataInputStream(conexion.getInputStream());
         salida = new DataOutputStream(conexion.getOutputStream());

         //Vamos  aleer el mensaje del cliente
         String nombreCliente = entrada.readUTF(); System.out.println("Conexión n " +num+ " mensaje: "+ nombreCliente);

         //Le respondemos al cliente
         salida.writeUTF("Buenos días, " +nombreCliente+ ", Hoy es sábado, día de clase");
         conexion.close();
     }
 }catch (IOException e) {
}
```

**CLIENT**

```
public class Cliente {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Socket cliente;
    DataInputStream entrada;
    DataOutputStream salida;
    String mensaje, respuesta;
    String nombreCliente;

    try{
        //Vamos a crear el socket para conectarnos al puerto 5000 del servidor
        cliente = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(),5000);
        entrada = new DataInputStream(cliente.getInputStream());

        //Creamos los canales de entrada/salida
        salida = new DataOutputStream(cliente.getOutputStream());
        mensaje = "Hola soy el cliente ";
        nombreCliente = "Luis Salgado Manzano";


        //Enviamos el mensaje que queremos al servidor mediante esta instrucción

        salida.writeUTF(nombreCliente);

        //Leemos la respuesta
        respuesta = entrada.readUTF();
        System.out.println( mensaje + nombreCliente);
        System.out.println("Respuesta del servidor: " + respuesta);


        //Cerramos la conexión
        cliente.close();
    }catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error: "+e.getMessage());
    }   
}
}
```

Comment: Your client tries to port 5000, but I don't see anywhere in the server code where it binds to port 5000?

Answer (score 0):

When you use the parameterless constructor of `ServerSocket()` what you get is an unbound instance.  You have 2 choices:

- Provide the port information in the call to the `ServerSocket` constructor
- Use the parameterless constructor and then make a call to the bind method.  The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#bind-java.net.SocketAddress-) explains this.  You will have to provide a `InetSocketAddress` with the details of the server and port number. [InetSocketAddress](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/InetSocketAddress.html)

The difference between the 2 methods is that the second will give you the opportunity to distinguish between 'localhost' and whatever network adapter your PC has.  You may want to restrict the visibility of your server socket to a particular one of these.  Obviously it's not magic and you can't bind the server socket to an IP of another machine you don't control but you may want to bind to 127.0.0.1 or to 192.168.x.x or whatever adapter you want to use.